# Laravel User model Max 15 characters allowed for username

Tags: laravel

I am very new to coding and I am looking for someone to help me to set Max limit for username allowed to be 15 characters. How can that be done.

I am preety much confused which file should I edit is it user.php or controller file or validation file.

Comment: Well, all in doc https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation (use `max`) , you can validate in the controller or in FormRequest

Comment: As a beginner, the first thing you should do is read the docs. As a beginner on SO: Always include the code you've tried and is not working. we help you with your code, We do not explain how-to or write code for you

Answer (score 3):

you will have to create a controller and add something like:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'username' => 'required|max:15',
        ]);

        //your code
    }
}
```